# iOS: Should I use a delegate or an NSNotification in this situation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

I have a database that updates with new data constantly. I use this data as my datasource for my `UITableView`. Currently, I am using `NSNotifications` to alert my `UITableView` to insert, delete or update new data. However, I've been thinking it would be much better to use `delegates` because it is one on one.

Here is some code to better demonstrate what is going on.

```
- (void)insertObject:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSNumber *object = [notification object];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.data insertObject:object atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
 }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771606/objective-c-delegate-or-c-style-block-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a larger scope, database updates are typically an event that many parts of your project could be interested in.  This is why Core Data itself uses notifications, rather than a delegate approach.  Yes, you could go either way, but I would tend to follow Apple's lead on this pattern. (maddy's comment to your post does have an excellent explanation btw)